# Error converting VARCHAR to DATETIME with timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert this string '2015-07-27T02:06:17+0000' into a date using:

```
SET @DATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, @CreatedDate, 127)
```

Where `@DATE` is declared as `DATETIME` and `@CreatedDate` is declared as `VARCHAR(50)`

But I am getting this error:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Check this link from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Yep been reading that for about an hour now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Cast(@CreatedDate as datetime)
```

Comment: First one looks like you are converting a varchar to a varchar - this does not work whether it is varchar or datetime. Second one does not work either. Still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
declare @v varchar(10)
set @v=cast(@CreatedDate as varchar) 
SET @DATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, @v, 127)
```

Comment: Ya, sorry it should have been @v instead of @CreatedDate at line num 3

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed this by removing the timezone (as I did not need it). I did this using `LEFT`

```
SET @DATE = CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@CreatedDate, 19), 126)
```

This effectively cut off the timezone part which means I could use the 126 Date-time style.